# Не экранируется точка в условии ИЛИ

Tags: awk

Подскажите, пожалуйста. Не работает установка разделителя в awk. Выражение

```
echo один,два.три | awk -F"(\.)" '{print "1="$1, "2="$2}'
```

работает корректно, но если добавить в разделитель, например, запятую, то работать перестаёт...

```
echo один,два.три | awk -F"(\.|,)" '{print "1="$1, "2="$2}'
```

В чём причина? Само регулярное выражение (.|,) ведь корректно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала, то, что вы хотите, в данном случае
пишется проще:

```sh
$ echo один,два.три | awk -F '[,.]' '{print "1="$1, "2="$2}'
1=один 2=два
$
```

В вашем же коде вы используете двойные кавычки,
которые могут проглатывать экранирование. Помимо этого
надо помнить, что *Awk*; принимает вашу строку
и скармливает её своему парсеру регекспов, а значит надо
экранировать дважды:

```sh
$ echo один,два.три | awk -F '(\\.|,)' '{print "1="$1, "2="$2}'
1=один 2=два
$
```

См. также:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53030404/1892060
- https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html
- https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/gawk-3.1.1/html_node/Escape-Sequences.html

Comment: спасибо. Всё дело в двойном экранировании. Использование кавычек или апострофа на результат не влияет. Конструкцию [.,] я не использую, т.к. в реальном примере условий больше. И также меня смутило, что не работает через \x. Например, конструкция (\xc2\xa0|\x20|\xe2\x80\x94|\x2e) работает, пока туда не добавлена точка - \x2e. В примере \xe2\x80\x94 - тире; \xc2\xa0- это неразрывный пробел.

Comment: То, о чём вы говорите в этом комментарии, — это отдельный вопрос.  Но решение то же.  Вам надо добавить ``\\`` перед ``\x2e``.